# Has anyone used the KalmanFilter Opencv libraries inside ROS?

Tags: ros, opencv, kalman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was wondering if someone has used the Kalman filter of Opencv inside ROS. The "normal" Opencv program works perfectly, but when i use it inside ros (The same code), it throws me the following error:

```
‘KF’ does not name a type
 KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(4, 4) << 1,0,1,0,   0,1,0,1,  0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,1);
```

The relevant include is:

```
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
```

That is the same that I use in the normal Opencv code, but in ROS it doesnt work.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213948/has-anyone-used-the-kalmanfilter-opencv-libraries-inside-ros?/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've been doing this somethimes.
It is hard to debug this without more code.
But do you have `KF` initialized?  `KF` is just an object type, right?

So have you done somthing like the following anywhere in your code?

```
cv::KalmanFilter KF
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-18**:
Yeah, here is it:
int stateSize = 4;
int measSize = 2;
int contrSize = 0;
unsigned int type = CV_32F;
KalmanFilter KF(stateSize, measSize, contrSize)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-20**:
Do you have the code somewhere available? Because with only this I cannot help more.
Everything seems fine, as far as I see.
Only difference we have is that we explicitly `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`, but that shouldn't make a difference.
Another guess: Do you link against `OpenCV_LIBRARIES`?